# How can I keep playing the UILocalNotification sound until user dismiss it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

As titled, I use UILocalNotification for alarm purposes. But the sound is only played once.

**I would like to keep the sound playing until user dismisses the notification, and only one notification item will be showed in Notification Center.**

There are two ways doing this, but none is well enough.

**1. First:** I can fire up to 64 notifications one by one, when the alarm time arrives, the alarm sound will be played multiple times(up to 64 times), as if it's been played endlessly. But this will leave too many items in Notification Center, which annoying me. Is there any way to combine these items showed in Notification Center into one?

**2. Second:** I assume there is a way to fire a single notification, and keep playing its sound. But right now I can only play sound within 30 seconds once.

Answer (score 2):

1) For first point it is not possible.
2) You can not playing sound constantly when single notification arrives until user dismisses notification manually.
so,both the scenarios are not possible. Please read briefly [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html).